# SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync always return Failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

After converting my application from .NET Framework 4.6 to .NET Core 2 I made the requested changes to the database to support the new identity model, namely a few fields added to AspNetUsers and new tables.

Logging works fine in .NET Core.

Now I need to go back to the .NET Framework 4.6 app and when I try to login, SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync always returns Failure.
I checked the queries using SQL Profiler and I cannot see any wrong query (no error in any of the queries run).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers](
    [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [UserKeyId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEndDateUtc] [datetime] NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [CreationDate] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('1900-01-01T00:00:00.000'),
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NormalizedEmail] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [NormalizedUserName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LockoutEnd] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Where it fails (i.e. result = SignInStatus.Failure):

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
```

In AspNetUsers table: Email = UserName

I don't think I need to rollback the changes made to the DB, so how can I find out the exact reason PasswordSignInAsync returns Failure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was with the hash.
With my old app in .NET Framework 4.6, it was using Identity 2.0.
When I converted my app to .NET Core 2, I actually created a new project and migrated code file by file, so it used the much stronger Identity 3.0. As a not-so-nice feature, the hash is rewritten when you login, so the password hashes were rewritten with Identity 3.0, which my old app could not decode.

There is however an option that you can set .NET Core to prevent the use of Identity 3.0.

You just have to add this line in ConfigureServices in Startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options =>
    options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2
);
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, at some point, I could not login into one of the environments and then I removed [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] from Login post action and this issue started to happen. Only reregistering a user seems to work at this point.

Answer (score 0):

check

update AspNetUsers set EmailConfirmed = 1